# Proof of a set inclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $\{E_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence ( i.e. $E_{n+1}\subset E_n)$.Let $\displaystyle E=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ and $F_n=E_n\setminus E_{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. I want to prove that $\displaystyle E_p\setminus E=\bigcup_{n=p}^\infty F_n$.

I'm unable to prove it directly. So I am trying to prove it by showing each-side is a subset of another-side.
I already prove that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=p}^\infty F_n \subset E_p\setminus E$.
But now I want to prove the reverse inclusion , where I stuck.

Please help me in reverse inclusion. Otherwise if direct proof of equality is possible then tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in E_p \setminus E$. Then $x \in E_p$ and $x \not\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Hence for some $k > p$, we have $x \not\in E_k$.

Define $m$ to be the minimal such $k$. Then $x \in E_{m-1}$, but $x \not\in E_{m}$.

Therefore $\displaystyle x \in F_{m-1} \subset \bigcup_{n=p}^\infty F_n$.